# Julia: Efficiency and indicating argument types

Tags: function, methods, types, julia

I have three related questions about specifying types of function arguments and outputs.  I'm defining a function f that I expect to call many times, so I'm looking to improve efficiency everywhere I can.  My function definition looks something like this:

```
function f(x, y)
    ...
    return z
end
```

I know that `x` will be an Array{Float64,1}, `y` will be an Array{Float64,2}, and `z` will be a Float64.

My questions are:

1. Is there an efficiency benefit to specifying the types of the inputs
   in the function definition, i.e. `function f(x::Array{Float64}, y::Array{Float64})`?
2. Is there any additional benefit to making the types more specific by specifying that `x` is 1-dimensional and `y` is 2-dimensional, i.e. `function f(x::Array{Float64,1}, y::Array{Float64,2})`?
3. Is there any efficiency benefit to specifying the type of `z`, i.e. `function f(x::Array{Float64,1}, y::Array{Float64,2})::Float64`?

Thanks so much!  And apologies if these questions have been addressed previously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[In general, no (to all questions)](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Type-declarations). The beauty of Julia is that its compiler is excellent at figuring these things out for you on the fly. The [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-tips) is the best place to look for how to write efficient code, like making sure your function is [type-stable](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Write-%22type-stable%22-functions).

Comment: There is one small quirk - the way you specify argument types of functions might impact compilation time.

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge benefit for the human reader of the code. Consider the difference for a human reading for the first time (or perhaps after a long time away from the code) :

```
function f(x, y)
```

vs.

```
function f(x::Array{Float64}, y::Array{Float64})::Float64
```

Comment: If you want to do this, you should at least give type annotations that don't overly constrict the function (eg `function f(x::AbstractVector, y::AbstractMatrix)` ). Otherwise your function won't work with other element types, which can be very useful.

Comment: Whatever helps with the fact that humans are not as good as compiler in "figuring these things out ... on the fly." For a non trivial project, there will be multiple humans trying to comprehend the codebase.

Comment: This almost looks like an argument in favor of `f(x, y)`. It's a heck of a lot easier to read. The better way to document function arguments is to use [docstrings](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/documentation/). As @OscarSmith mentioned, it's all too easy to accidentally over-restrict the input and output types for a function.

Comment: Sure, and `f(x)` is even easier to read  ( oh and BTW x is tuple `Tuple{x::Array{Float64,1}, y::Array{Float64,2}`). Understanding is a bit more difficult.

Comment: Function argument annotations are used for *method dispatch*, not documentation. Docstrings are used for documentation.